# Real-time Java Specification

Tags: java, performance, caching

Are there any low-level differences between normal Java and the Real-time Java spec?

Im just critical because it still has the JVM and therefore you cannot directly access as much of the "bare metal" as one doing real-time would like ???

Comment: For the closers out there, it is a real question (albeit a naive one)

Answer (score 5):

Real-time has absolutely nothing to do with "accessing the bare metal". It's about the ability to say "I want this task to be finished within the next 100ms", and have the system ensure that it will indeed happen, and that the executing thread will not be swapped out, it will not have to wait for a full GC, and it will get all locks it needs before any lower-priority tasks do.

The Real-time Java spec is all about this requirement, and that does indeed require a lot of low-level changes in thread scheduling, GC, and synchronization.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind, real-time doesn't even mean faster (often it is slower), but there is _no chance_ it will complete after the time requirement.  It either completes prior to the time requirement or fails.

Comment: I think another way of thinking about real-time is that the actual clock time that something happens is one of your critical pieces of data; it often leads to having to do things quickly, but not necessarily.  You can have systems that are real-time in nature but not blazingly fast.  A requirement like "have to finish this in 100ms" comes from the fact that, starting in 101ms, you might have something else that you have to process; you can handle the processing a different way, but the fact that the time that signal arrives is significant is characteristic of real-time software.